# Merging two code snippets results in error

Tags: javascript, revolution-slider

When I insert slider code into my HTML document it gives me an error of:

> TypeError: $ is not a function. (In '$(window)', '$' is undefined)

Here is my current code:

```
    //Car Appear In View
    function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
        var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

        var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top + 180;
        var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height() - 500;

        return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
    }

    $(window).scroll(function () {
       $('.running-car').each(function () {
            if (isScrolledIntoView(this) === true) {
                $(this).addClass('in-view');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('in-view');
            }
        });
    });

    //threesixty degree
    window.onload = init;
    var car;
    function init(){

        car = $('.360-car').ThreeSixty({
            totalFrames: 52, // Total no. of image you have for 360 slider
            endFrame: 52, // end frame for the auto spin animation
            currentFrame: 3, // This the start frame for auto spin
            imgList: '.threesixty_images', // selector for image list
            progress: '.spinner', // selector to show the loading progress
            imagePath:'demos/car/images/360degree-cars/', // path of the image assets
            filePrefix: '', // file prefix if any
            ext: '.png', // extention for the assets
            height: 887,
            width: 500,
            navigation: true,
            responsive: true,
        });
    };

    // Rev Slider
    var tpj=jQuery;
    var revapi424;
    tpj(document).ready(function() {
        if(tpj("#rev_slider_424_1").revolution == undefined){
            revslider_showDoubleJqueryError("#rev_slider_424_1");
        }else{
            revapi424 = tpj("#rev_slider_424_1").show().revolution({
                sliderType:"carousel",
                jsFileLocation:"include/rs-plugin/js/",
                sliderLayout:"auto",
                dottedOverlay:"none",
                delay:7000,
                navigation: {
                    keyboardNavigation:"off",
                    keyboard_direction: "horizontal",
                    mouseScrollNavigation:"off",
                    mouseScrollReverse:"default",
                    onHoverStop:"off",
                    touch:{
                        touchenabled:"on",
                        swipe_threshold: 75,
                        swipe_min_touches: 1,
                        swipe_direction: "horizontal",
                        drag_block_vertical: false
                    }
                    ,
                    arrows: {
                        style:"uranus",
                        enable:false,
                        hide_onmobile:false,
                        hide_onleave:true,
                        hide_delay:200,
                        hide_delay_mobile:1200,
                        tmp:'',
                        left: {
                            h_align:"left",
                            v_align:"center",
                            h_offset:-10,
                            v_offset:0
                        },
                        right: {
                            h_align:"right",
                            v_align:"center",
                            h_offset:-10,
                            v_offset:0
                        }
                    },
                    carousel: {
                        maxRotation: 65,
                        vary_rotation: "on",
                        minScale: 55,
                        vary_scale: "on",
                        horizontal_align: "center",
                        vertical_align: "center",
                        fadeout: "on",
                        vary_fade: "on",
                        maxVisibleItems: 5,
                        infinity: "off",
                        space: 0,
                        stretch: "on"
                    }
                    ,
                    tabs: {
                        style:"ares",
                        enable:true,
                        width:270,
                        height:80,
                        min_width:270,
                        wrapper_padding: 10,
                        wrapper_color:"transparent",
                        wrapper_opacity:"0.5",
                        tmp:'<div class="tp-tab-content">  <span class="tp-tab-date">{{param1}}</span>  <span class="tp-tab-title">{{title}}</span></div><div class="tp-tab-image"></div>',
                        visibleAmount: 7,
                        hide_onmobile: false,
                        hide_under:420,
                        hide_onleave:false,
                        hide_delay_mobile:1200,
                        hide_delay:200,
                        direction:"horizontal",
                        span:true,
                        position:"outer-bottom",
                        space:20,
                        h_align:"left",
                        v_align:"bottom",
                        h_offset:0,
                        v_offset:0
                    }
                },
                visibilityLevels:[1240,1024,778,480],
                gridwidth:[1240,992,768,420],
                gridheight:[600,500,960,720],
                lazyType:"single",
                shadow:0,
                spinner:"off",
                stopLoop:"off",
                stopAfterLoops: 0,
                stopAtSlide: 1,
                shuffle:"off",
                autoHeight:"off",
                hideThumbsOnMobile:"off",
                hideSliderAtLimit:0,
                hideCaptionAtLimit:0,
                hideAllCaptionAtLilmit:0,
                debugMode:false,
                fallbacks: {
                    simplifyAll:"off",
                    nextSlideOnWindowFocus:"off",
                    disableFocusListener:false,
                }
            });
        }
    }); /*ready*/

    // Video on play on hover
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('.videoplay-on-hover').hover( function(){
            if( $(this).find('video').length > 0 ) {
                $(this).find('video').get(0).play();
            }
        }, function(){
            if( $(this).find('video').length > 0 ) {
                $(this).find('video').get(0).pause();
            }
        });
    });
```

Here is the code I am trying to add:

```
            var tpj=jQuery;
    tpj.noConflict();

    tpj(document).ready(function() {

        var apiRevoSlider = tpj('#rev_slider_k_fullwidth').show().revolution(
        {
            sliderType:"standard",
            sliderLayout:"fullwidth",
            delay:9000,
            navigation: {
                arrows:{enable:true}
            },
            responsiveLevels:[1240,1024,778,480],
            visibilityLevels:[1240,1024,778,480],
            gridwidth:[1240,1024,778,480],
            gridheight:[600,768,960,720],
        });

        apiRevoSlider.bind("revolution.slide.onloaded",function (e) {
            setTimeout( function(){ SEMICOLON.slider.sliderParallaxDimensions(); }, 400 );
        });

        apiRevoSlider.bind("revolution.slide.onchange",function (e,data) {
            SEMICOLON.slider.revolutionSliderMenu();
        });

    });
```

It gives me the errors of:

> TypeError: $ is not a function. (In '$(window)', '$' is undefined)

or

> TypeError: $ is not a function. (In '$('.running-car')', '$' is
>   undefined) TypeError: $ is not a function. (In '$('.360-car')', '$' is
>   undefined)

Depending on if I insert the new code before or after the other code, independently both work just fine.

Comment: If you are using `tpj=jQuery;` then instead of using `$(xyz)` use `tpj('xyz')` everywhere. Also, you reference to `$', `jQuery` and '`tpj` are inconsistent. Declare this at the top and use it consistently.

Comment: @fiveelements thank you, post that as an answer and I will mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `tpj=jQuery;` then instead of using `$(xyz)` use `tpj('xyz')` everywhere.

Also, your reference to `$`, `jQuery` and `tpj` are inconsistent. Declare the following at the top with `noConflict()` optionally and use `tpj` consistently wherever you are using jQuery based code.

```
var tpj = jQuery;
tpj.noConflict();
```